# Best way to write a recursive function in C++?

Tags: c++, algorithm, function, recursion

**Question**
I wish to know if this is a viable way to implement variable depth recursion so that I can run a function at each step and any better/other solutions to the description problem.
**Description**
Suppose I wish to have a function that fills an array either in pattern
`x,y,x,y,x,y`where x and y are variables defined by some algorithm
and `x,y,z,x,y,z` where x, y and z are variables defined by the same algorithm.

This should continue for all number of variables. Is this a viable way to implement it.

```
void recurse_n(int n)
{
    while(n > 0)
    {
        --n;
        recurse_n(n);
        n = 0;
        // Use algorithm here
    }
}
```

EDIT: Removed the incorrect return type previously referred to. Brainfart.

Comment: is that not an infinite loop because recurse_n will always be called before reaching 0

Comment: @PowerRoy: No, it's not an infinite loop. If n is 0 or less there will be no recursion. If n is greater than 0, there will be recursion, but for each recursion the n will be less, so it will always reach the base case of 0.

Comment: No, it is not an infinite loop because n is decremented before calling recurse_n, so eventually it will be called with an argument of 0. Tracing back up the call stack they will each then end because once recurse_n returns it will set n to 0 and break out of the loop.

Comment: Are you asking for help with defining the algorithm to create your sequence x,y,x,y,x,y etc. or are you asking about how to set up a recursive function?

Comment: This code is **wrong** : where are the `return` statements ? And why the hell do you need a `int` return type if you don't use it ?

Comment: @DaveJohnston I'm asking how to set up the recursive function, not the algorithm itself inside the recursive function.

Comment: @Brian R. Bondy See what I wrote to Dave.

Comment: This question (or at least (expected) the answer and original code) is not C++, it is C. Use a std::vector if you use C++, then you won't need any recursive function to fill it.

Comment: This is not a good use of recursion, IMO. Seems like overkill. You'd be better off just using some kind of loop...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So, based on your comment you want to know the best way to set up a recursive function.  What you have done will work, but it is convoluted and slightly confusing.  What I would do to simplify it is:

```
void recurse_n(int n) {
    if (n <= 0) {
        // Break-out condition
        return;
    }

    --n;
    recurse_n(n);

    // Your algorithm stuff here.
}
```

That will make it easier to see what is going on.  One thing I would add though is that you might want to do the algorithm stuff before the call to recurse_n, but that all depends on what your algorithm is doing.

If you think about it, the way I have written it, it will recurse until n is less than or equal to 0 before doing any of the algorithm work.  It might be that you want to do the algorithm work then recurse.

Comment: Thanks, that's pretty well what I was chasing along with a confirmation that this was correct code. Hopefully we get a bit more discussion on complexity and such before this dies down now with an accepted answer.

Answer (score 4):

First of all, use a std::vector and a loop (I'm assuming x(), y() and z() return the `int`s you need, you could also use a vector there to store the values):

```
void fill( std::vector<int> &vec, std::vector<int> &values )
{
    size_t nValues = values.size();
    size_t sz = vec.size();
    for( size_t i=0; i<sz; i=i+nValues )
    {
        for( size_t j=0; j<nValues; ++j )
        {
            vec[i] = values[j];
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> vec;
    std::vector<int> values;
    /* fill values vector here */
    vec.resize( 512 ); // (arbitraty) size you need
    fill( vec, values );

    return 0;
}
```

This is more C++-ish and much faster than a recursive function. Also: store x, y, and z values so that the corresponding algorithm only executes once.

Comment: That doesn't really help because your fill vector algorithm is bound to only filling x and y. I want a general one which fill any number of dimensions. Not just two dimensions.

Comment: I updated my answer. There might be better ways, avoiding the second loop, but this is already O(n²), which is IMHO the lowest complexity possible (someone correct me if I'm wrong)

Comment: Thanks. That's rather nice now.

Comment: Aside from not doing anything (several typos), a simpler way would be something like this:

    `for (size_t i = 0, j = 0; i < sz; ++i, j = (j + 1) % values.size()) vec[i] = values[j];`

Comment: Did I get 'm all? :s I didn't take the liberty to use your `%` variant, that would be stealing ;)

Answer (score 2):

I do not think this is a viable way to do it, since: Let `T(n)` denote the running time of your function (dependent on input parameter `n`).

The base case `n=0` yields following running time: `T(0)=c`, i.e. some constant runtime `c`.

Now you can define a recursive formula for the running time where `n>0`: `T(n)=sum(i = 0 to n-1: T(i))`.

If you solve this equation you get that `T(n)=O(2^n)`, which means that your algorithm is exponential, which means that it is not tractable in practice.

Comment: Would that not also mean that implementing this by writing nested for loops would result in an exponential algorithm also, meaning that it is a known problem that with dimensional increases you get this increase in running time, and this just has to be accepted when dealing with high numbers of dimensions?

Answer (score 1):

I'm a little unclear on the question, but it sounds like you have a set of variables `a, b, c, ..., z` and you want to fill an array so it contains `a, b, c, ..., z, a, b, c, ..., z, a, ...`. If so, it's probably simplest to put the source variables in their own one-pass array `a, b, c, ..., z` and `memcpy` it to the destination array until it's filled

```
#define NUM 3
int a, b, c; // source variables
void fill(int* arr, unsigned int size) {
    int src[] = {a, b, c};
    unsigned int i;
    for(i = 0; i < size / NUM; i++)
        memcpy(arr + (NUM * i), src, sizeof(int) * NUM);
    memcpy(arr + (NUM * i), src, sizeof(int) * (size % NUM));
}
```

Comment: Specifically I wish to generate cloud co-ordinates in an even distribution (of some sort), representing a n-cube and store them in a 1D array, however I only require a way to implement recursion to a depth set on runtime.

Answer (score 1):

JimDaniel is right, the recursion here is an overkill. You're not returning anything from the function and it looks like you're only using "n" to control the number of recursions. Using a simple for-loop would be much clearer + more efficient.

Answer (score 1):

Recursion to fill an array is a valid (even the best) option if your algorithm meets these requirements:

1. The value at position `n` depends on the values of at least some of the values that came before it
2. There is no (known) way to determine the value at position `n` without first determining the earlier values that it depends on.

An example that fits these requirements are the [fibonacci numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number). Because you can't determine the n-th number without first determining all earlier numbers (though some shortcuts exist).

An example that doesn't fit these requirements is an array that is filled with the square of the index, where the value at position `n` is just `n^2`.

Finally, I'd suggest you rewrite your function according to the pattern in DaveJohnston's answer to your question if possible.